# Create multiple object lists from one, based on an object parameter in Kotlin

Tags: android, list, algorithm, kotlin, processing-efficiency

I Have a list of object with an Int attribute, like this:

| List |
| --- |
| id: 1 |
| id: 1 |
| id: 2 |
| id: 2 |
| id: 3 |

and i want to create different list based on that attribute, like this:

| List A | List B | List C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id: 1 | id: 2 | id: 3 |
| id: 1 | id: 2 |  |

i found some ways to do it but i wanted to know if there was an efficient way, maybe using some method that kotlin already provide.

Comment: Do you mean efficient in time complexity or just a pretty magic method that do it?

Comment: ìif a magical method existed it would be great, but if i have to create it i want it to be efficient in time complexity way

Answer (score 2):

```
data class Test(
  val id: Int,
  val text: String
)

val list = listOf(
  Test(1, "a"),
  Test(1, "b"),
  Test(2, "c"),
  Test(2, "d"),
  Test(3, "e")
)

val result = list
  .groupBy { test -> test.id }
  .map { it.value }

result.forEach(::println)
```

Output:

```
[Test(id=1, text=a), Test(id=1, text=b)]
[Test(id=2, text=c), Test(id=2, text=d)]
[Test(id=3, text=e)]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the groupBy: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html

It will return a map, that the key is the property value that you used to group by, and the value is the list.